# Are there any libraries for generating Python source?

Tags: python, code-generation

I'd like to write a code generation tool that will allow me to create sourcefiles for dynamically generated classes.  I can create the class and use it in code, but it would be nice to have a sourcefile both for documentation and to allow something to import.

Does such a thing exist?  I've seen [sourcecodegen](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sourcecodegen/0.6.11), but I'd rather avoid messing with the ast trees as they're not portable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any off-the-shelf library, but have a look at the Python templating engines [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/) and [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/). They can both generate Python source behind the scenes (they convert text templates to Python code and then to Python bytecode).

Comment: +1: Just use a template engine.  It works well.  That's what we do.